# setClickable() and setEnabled() methods is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

setClickable() and setEnabled() aren't working but other methods like setVisibilty() working very well
so what is supposed to happen is when starting action mode the recycler view should be disabled and non-clickable.
i had searched the web for solutions but nothing of them were useful for me

fragment class

```
public class MemoryFragment extends Fragment {
public static ListView listView;
private AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener multiChoiceModeListener;
public static List<Folders> foldersList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ListViewBaseAdapter listViewBaseAdapter;
public static File rootDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
final int permission_code = 100;

    public static List<String> recyclerList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

    public static boolean isActionMode = false;
    public static List<String> selectedFolders = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ActionMode actionMode = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            if(recyclerList != null){
                recyclerList.clear();
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(listViewBaseAdapter != null) {
                listViewBaseAdapter.clear();
                listViewBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){

        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_memory, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerList.add(rootDirectory.getAbsolutePath());

        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        for(int x = 0; x < permissions.length; x++)
            checkPermissions(permissions, permission_code);

        String[] rootNames = rootDirectory.list();
        File[] files = rootDirectory.listFiles();
        for (int x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            if (files[x].isDirectory())
                foldersList.add(new Folders(R.drawable.ic_folders, rootNames[x], files[x]));
            else
                foldersList.add(new Folders(R.drawable.ic_file, rootNames[x], files[x]));
        }

        listViewBaseAdapter = new ListViewBaseAdapter(getContext(), foldersList);

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewBaseAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Folders folder = foldersList.get(position);
                String fileName = folder.getFile().getName();
                recyclerList.add(fileName);
                Folders.newFolders(position, foldersList, listViewBaseAdapter, recyclerViewAdapter);
            }
        });

        multiChoiceModeListener = new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_menu, menu);
                isActionMode = true;
                actionMode = mode;
                recyclerView.setEnabled(false);            //here is the problem 1
                recyclerView.setClickable(false);          //here is the problem 2
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                isActionMode = false;
                actionMode = null;
                selectedFolders.clear();
                ListViewBaseAdapter.checkStates.clear();
            }
        };
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(multiChoiceModeListener);

        return view;
    }


    public void checkPermissions(String[] permissions, int permission_code){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), permissions, permission_code);
        else
            return;
    }

    public void requestPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode){
        for (int x = 0; x < permissions.length; x++)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case permission_code: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] + grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
    }
}
```

Recycler Adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> folderNames;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List folderNames){
    this.folderNames = folderNames;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_adapter, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow);
    holder.textView.setText(folderNames.get(position));
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(folderNames.get(0).equals(SDCardFragment.path))
                Folders.backToFolder(position, SDCardFragment.recyclerList, SDCardFragment.listViewBaseAdapter, RecyclerViewAdapter.this);
            else
                Folders.backToFolder(position, MemoryFragment.recyclerList, MemoryFragment.listViewBaseAdapter, RecyclerViewAdapter.this);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return folderNames.size();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A `RecyclerView` is not clickable -- the items in the `RecyclerView` are clickable.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks so how can i prevent and disable clicking of it's items, i tried to make the items static and it's worked but there values have changed and this shouldn't happen

Comment: "i prevent and disable clicking of it's items" -- do not call `setOnClickListener()`. Or, call it and ignore the event when you are in this "disabled" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow);

    if(MemoryFragment.isActionMode)
        holder.textView.setEnabled(false);
    else
        holder.textView.setEnabled(true);

    holder.textView.setText(folderNames.get(position));
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(folderNames.get(0).equals(SDCardFragment.path))
                Folders.backToFolder(position, SDCardFragment.recyclerList, SDCardFragment.listViewBaseAdapter, RecyclerViewAdapter.this);
            else
                Folders.backToFolder(position, MemoryFragment.recyclerList, MemoryFragment.listViewBaseAdapter, RecyclerViewAdapter.this);
        }
    });


@Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_menu, menu);
            isActionMode = true;
            actionMode = mode;
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            isActionMode = false;
            actionMode = null;
            selectedFolders.clear();
            ListViewBaseAdapter.checkStates.clear();
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

in a simple words i used the `isActionsMode` variable as indicator for recycler `textView.setEnabled()` and then apply `recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`in the action mode creation and destruction.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. You are asking recyclerview to disable clicks which us wrong. RecyclerView'ss every item have a different click listener which you are handling inside onItemClick method already.

If you want to disable clicks or toucher for RecyclerView's childs then yehat you can do is
Taking a global variable lets say:
private boolean isclickAllowed = true

Then in you itemClickListener add this check

```
if(isclickAllowed) {
// your code here
}
```

Then whenever you want your Click listener to be disabled
Just change this variable to "false"

Like in your case when in ActionMode change this variable to "false"

And when you want to enable clicks back just change the value to "true".

Comment: thank you for your help, i used IsActionMode instead of creating new variable